# Scala case class member parameterized with wildcard types does not infer type bound when called

Tags: scala

I searched online but didn't get a useful result. Maybe this is stupid but I'm trying to make it work.
The description of my question can be shown in the following example:

```scala
trait EnumType
class MyEnum extends EnumType

trait Coherence[S <: EnumType] {
    def printS(s: S): Unit
}

class MyCoherence extends Coherence[EnumType] {
    override def printS(s: EnumType): Unit = println("printS in MyCoherence")
}

case class MyCaseClass(coh: Coherence[_ <: EnumType])

object HelloWorld {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val myCoh = new MyCoherence
       val m = MyCaseClass(myCoh)
       val myEnum = new MyEnum

       myCoh.printS(myEnum)
       m.coh.printS(myEnum) // >>> problematic line 21
      println("Hello, world!")
   }
}
```

As you can see, I have a case class `MyCaseClass` which takes an instance of `Coherence[_ <: EnumType]` as parameter.

This instance has a simple `printS()` which prints some message.

In the `main`, when I try to call `printS` of `m.coh`, the compiler gives the following error:

```
$scalac *.scala
HelloWorld.scala:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : myEnum.type (with underlying type MyEnum)
 required: _$1
       m.coh.printS(myEnum)
                    ^
one error found
```

It seems that the type bound of `coh` is erased when I do `m.coh.printS` (`_$1` instead of `_$1 <: EnumType`).

I wonder whether I'm missing something for using `printS` in such a way? Thanks

Comment: Why not just `case class MyCaseClass[E <: EnumType](coh: Coherence[E])`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for replying! Yes, I can add a type parameter and it should work. The problem is that this `MyCaseClass` was without type parameters and is being used by many classes as a `val` member. I suppose I have to modify the signature of those classes but I don't want to do that (which might not be true?)

Comment: I believe you're missing variance on Coherence type argument, i.e. `trait Coherence[-S <: EnumType]`

Answer (score 0):

The type bound isn't erased, just not printed in this situation. The problem is that `m.coh` could be a `Coherence[SomeOtherEnum]`:

```
class SomeOtherEnum extends EnumType
class OtherCoherence extends Coherence[SomeOtherEnum] {
    override def printS(s: SomeOtherEnum): Unit = ???
}

val m = MyCaseClass(new OtherCoherence)
```

Because this `m` and yours have the same type, `m.coh.printS(myEnum)` should type-check in both cases or in neither, and it obviously can't work here: it calls  `OtherCoherence.printS()` which only accepts `SomeOtherEnum`.

You can make it compile by casting `m.coh`:

```scala
m.coh.asInstanceOf[Coherence[EnumType]].printS(myEnum)
```

But it's unsafe due to the above: if `m.coh` is a `MyCoherence`, it will work; if `m.coh` is an `OtherCoherence`, it will end up trying to cast `myEnum` to `SomeOtherEnum` and throw an exception.